# React Native App always starts at initial route when resume

Tags: reactjs, native

Reproduce:

1- the app name is PX, having multiple screens

2- open the app, navigate to a screen having one text field

3- input some text in that field

4- press Home button (or switch to other apps)

5- switch back to PX app.

If PX app uses wix’s react-native-navigation, at step 5, we still see the text field with some text we entered beforehand

But, if PX app uses react-navigation, at step 5, it always show the initial screen (say Splash screen). I don’t really want this.

I have my own reason not to use wix’s library. So please help me with react-navigation: i want the app remains the latest screen and its state after get back to foreground.